# assign a value based on which row in a pair is higher

Tags: r

I have:

```
> dput(for_stack)
structure(list(id = c("20230420-01", "20230420-02", "2023042110-01", 
"2023042110-02", "2023042112-01", "2023042112-02", "2023042114-01", 
"2023042114-02", "2023042214-01", "2023042214-02"), pair_id = c(20230420L, 
20230420L, 2023042110L, 2023042110L, 2023042112L, 2023042112L, 
2023042114L, 2023042114L, 2023042214L, 2023042214L), mean_blast = c(3.82352941176471, 
4.46153846153846, 1.71428571428571, 1.0625, 4.8125, 4, 3.5, 1.25, 
4.9375, 4.5)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are two rows per `pair_id` and I want to know which row in each pair contains a higher value for `mean_blast` such that:

```
> dput(for_stack)
structure(list(id = c("20230420-01", "20230420-02", "2023042110-01", 
"2023042110-02", "2023042112-01", "2023042112-02", "2023042114-01", 
"2023042114-02", "2023042214-01", "2023042214-02"), pair_id = c(20230420L, 
20230420L, 2023042110L, 2023042110L, 2023042112L, 2023042112L, 
2023042114L, 2023042114L, 2023042214L, 2023042214L), mean_blast = c(3.82352941176471, 
4.46153846153846, 1.71428571428571, 1.0625, 4.8125, 4, 3.5, 1.25, 
4.9375, 4.5), higher = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

              id    pair_id mean_blast higher
1    20230420-01   20230420   3.823529  FALSE
2    20230420-02   20230420   4.461538   TRUE
3  2023042110-01 2023042110   1.714286   TRUE
4  2023042110-02 2023042110   1.062500  FALSE
5  2023042112-01 2023042112   4.812500   TRUE
6  2023042112-02 2023042112   4.000000  FALSE
7  2023042114-01 2023042114   3.500000   TRUE
8  2023042114-02 2023042114   1.250000  FALSE
9  2023042214-01 2023042214   4.937500   TRUE
10 2023042214-02 2023042214   4.500000  FALSE
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this with `summarize` and `group_by`, but I have not figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can use `max` by group:

```r
library(dplyr)

for_stack |>
  mutate(higher = mean_blast == max(mean_blast), .by = pair_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I end up with an extra column called <.by> full of the pair_ids. This is easy to drop by I am curious why it is happening

Comment: This is probably because you have not updated `dplyr` . Try to update; or use `for_stack |> group_by(pair_id) |> mutate(higher = mean_blast == max(mean_blast))`

Comment: yep, that worked :). It seems that loading `plyr` ruins `dplyr`... will have to keep that in mind.

Comment: If in a pair both have the same value, in this solution both get `TRUE`, which doesn't seem correct to me, since none is higher.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can use `rank` in `ave`, `2` is the higher value.

```
> transform(for_stack, higher=ave(mean_blast, pair_id, FUN=rank) == 2)
              id    pair_id mean_blast higher
1    20230420-01   20230420   3.823529  FALSE
2    20230420-02   20230420   4.461538   TRUE
3  2023042110-01 2023042110   1.714286   TRUE
4  2023042110-02 2023042110   1.062500  FALSE
5  2023042112-01 2023042112   4.812500   TRUE
6  2023042112-02 2023042112   4.000000  FALSE
7  2023042114-01 2023042114   3.500000   TRUE
8  2023042114-02 2023042114   1.250000  FALSE
9  2023042214-01 2023042214   4.937500   TRUE
10 2023042214-02 2023042214   4.500000  FALSE
```

If there are ties, both get `FALSE`.